# Cannot position MovieClips loaded with images based on their height

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I use the following code to load some banners: a "banner" is a clickable PNG image. I get the URL it must point to through a parameter of the AdLoader class.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.navigateToURL;
    import flash.filters.DropShadowFilter;
    import flash.filters.BitmapFilterQuality;
    //
    public class AdLoader extends MovieClip
    {
        var mcs = [];
        var loader:Loader;
        var URLs:Array;
        var flt:DropShadowFilter;
        var h:uint = 0;
        //
        public function AdLoader(ads:Object)
        {
            initFilters();
            //
            var adsLen = ads.u.length;
            URLs = ads.u;
            // here I create movieClips based on how many images I must load
            buildContainers(adsLen);
            //
            for (var i:uint=0; i<adsLen; i++)
            {
                //
                loader = new Loader();
                var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(ads.s[i]);
                loader.load(request);
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, __onLoadComplete);
                mcs[i].addChild(loader);
            }
        }
        //
        public function __onLoadComplete(e:Event)
        {
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, __onLoadComplete);

            //;
            var n = this.numChildren;
            //trace(n);
            //
            for (var j:uint=0; j<n; j++)
            {
                trace(j);
                h +=  this.getChildAt(j).height;
                this.getChildAt(j).y = j == 0 ? 0:h + 10;
            }
        }
        //
        public function gotoURL(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            var n = Number(e.target.parent.name.split("_")[1]);
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(URLs[n]);
            navigateToURL(request,"_blank");
        }
        //
        public function buildContainers(n)
        {
            for (var i:uint=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                var mcLoader = new MovieClip();
                mcLoader.name = "loader_" + i;
                mcLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, gotoURL);
                mcLoader.mouseEnabled = true;
                mcLoader.buttonMode = true;
                mcLoader.filters = new Array(flt);
                mcs.push(mcLoader);
                addChild(mcLoader);
            }
        }
        //
        public function initFilters()
        {
            //...removed
        }
    }
}
```

In practice, I create some MovieClip containers (loader_1, loader_2, etc.) and **in each container I want to load one image**.

What happens: when the images are loaded I want to position each image at the y+10 pixel of the preceding, so **if the first is at y:0 and its height is 140, I want the second image at y:150 (and so on)**. I can't understand what it happens but sometimes the code works, while most of the time it doesn't.

Anybody interested can download all the files [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B1EWtqLO5hiWMjVhYTFhM2QtYWFlNS00Y2Y4LThiYTUtNTliZWJlZTc4OGQ4&hl=en_US) (from the top left menu choose File, then "download original").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should first set the event handler and then start the loading:

```
loader.load(request);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, __onLoadComplete);
```

should be:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, __onLoadComplete);
loader.load(request);
```

Secondly, keep in mind that, since you are loading multiple images, the __onLoadComplete will be called multiple times (once for each image). But, the first time it is called, in your code you "remove" it from your loader object (which is actually the loader for the last image, since you are overwriting it in the loop). Also, the code for calculating the positions is wrong (especially since it is run before all the images are loaded). Anyway, this is one way it could be done:

```
var imagesLoaded:int = 0;
public function __onLoadComplete(e:Event)
{
    // we keep track how many images we have loaded so far
    imagesLoaded++;

    // if all the images are loaded, we will arrange them
    if(imagesLoaded == adsLen)
    {
        var n = this.numChildren;

        h = 0;
        for (var j:uint=0; j<n; j++)
        {                
            this.getChildAt(j).y = h;
            h += this.getChildAt(j).height + 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to look for some more examples on how to load multiple assets in AS3 (for example [this one](http://blog.molanphydesign.com/2008/08/17/loading-multiple-images-in-as3/)).

Comment: Thank you. The eventListener in that position is the result of many cut and paste when the code was not working. I see you don't remove the eventlistener in the body of the __onComplete method: shouldn't I remove it?

Comment: It doesn't matter. You are not using the loader to load anything else so it won't be firing the event again. But, anyway, the way you were doing it was wrong. You are making several loaders in the loop with `loader = new Loader();`. Each time your event handler gets called, you remove the listener from the loader that is assigned to the `loader` variable, which is actually the last of the loaders (the one created in the last iteration of the loop). To get the actual loader that has fired the event, do this `var l:Loader = Loader(e.currentTarget.loader);`.